# Do in-memory objects limited to user/session scope need to be thread-safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, thread-safety, deadlock

```
// Not thread-safe
class ShoppingCart {
    private List<Product> products;

    public void Add(Product p) { products.Add(p); }
    public void Remove(Product p) { products.Remove(p); }
}
```

Whenever user triggers an action associated with shopping cart, we pull it out and do what is needed.

```
// Could be a HTTP GET or AJAX pull
Add(Product product) {
    ShoppingCart cart = Session[User.ID];
    cart.Add(product);
}
```

My concern is that could the same user invoke multiple methods accessing the `ShoppingCart` causing dead-locks?

Comment: FWIW: It probably won't deadlock, but could corrupt state.

I think your real question is: "Does ASP.NET MVC automatically serialize requests?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question shouldn't be *do in-memory objects limited to user/session scope need to be thread-safe* but *do I have multiple threads reading and writing to the same shared memory instance (no matter where it comes from)*?

So if you never manually run some threads to do processing on this `Session[User.ID]` you don't need to synchronize it.